# Disable autocomple on el-time-picker and display value format Element-UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

Any who had worked with the ElementUI library for Vuejs.

Im using the `el-time-picker` component, right now when i focus it auto set the input with the current hour, but i want it to keep it blank, i had tried seting it default value to `null` but it doesn't work.

Also even thought i have this:

`:picker-options="{
    format: 'HH:mm',
}"`

The picker dropdown just show up hour and minutes but once selected, the input display hour:minutes:seconds, this also produce that if i type the hour, i gotta type it with seconds for get it to work, i don't want this behavior, just to display hh:mm and be able to type just it.

Any suggestions:? I'm trying to understand the code as right to try to overwrite the component.

#### Edit 1

Time picker code is simple, i just has the component with a few options:

```
<el-time-picker
    v-model="row.from"
    value-format="HH:mm"
    :picker-options="{
      format: 'HH:mm',
      selectableRange: '00:00:00 - 23:59:00',
    }"
    placeholder="Desde">
</el-time-picker>
```

Comment: Can you include your `el-time-picker` code here?

Comment: Sure, already done

Answer (score 0):

The initial (default) value for `row.from` must be an empty String, not `null`. The `format` option works only for the popup selector, not for the editbox. To achieve what you want you have to specify the `step` option like in this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ope13qwu/5/)

### UPDATE

The JSfiddle was updated.

Comment: First, the `step` option is only available for `time-select` component and not `time-picker` and second no matter the value of `row.from` it will set up the current time.

Comment: Updated the JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use the @focus event to change the default value:

https://jsfiddle.net/2q8ovLah/3/

```
 <el-time-picker placeholder = "HH:mm:ss"
                 value-format = "HH:mm:ss"
                 v-model = "time"
                 :editable = "false"
                 :picker-options = "{selectableRange: '00:00:01 - 23:59:59'}"
                 clearable
                 @focus = "focused">
  </el-time-picker>
```

---

```
data() {
  return {
    time: ''
  };
},
methods: {
  focused(){
    if(this.time === '') {
        this.time = '00:01:00'
    }
  }
}
```